# Почему происходит ошибка "поле отсутствует или пусто"?

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, микроразметка, opengraph

В валидаторе мироразметки от Яндекса появилась ошибка

> ОШИБКА: поле http://ogp.me/ns#url отсутствует или пусто.

В `heaeder.php` прописываю

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://site.ru">
```

Как правильно прописать значение `content=` чтобы для каждой страницы `url` был нужный от конкретной страницы, а не только от главной. Сайт на `Wordpress`.

И еще вопрос: подскажите, пожалуйста, где в `wordpress` хранится код с разметкой `opengraphs`, потому что с остальным `(http://ogp.me/ns#type, http://ogp.me/ns#title и т.д.)` проблем нет, это все указано, но в каком файле это прописано не могу найти. В `heaeder.php` этого нет.

Answer (score 0):

В `header` замените секцию `html` на примерно такое:

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> prefix="og: https://ogp.me/ns/article#">
```

Wordpress без плагина не умеет делать микроразметку.
Либо Yoast, либо AIOSEO, либо другой плагин отдельно для микроразметки.

Но конфликты все равно будут. Единственное, на мой взгляд, правильное решение использовать дополнительные поля и вывести все SEO через них.